# Regex: word after word in-between words

Tags: regex

considering this example text:

```
!important!this is a poor example of a sentence!important!
```

I try to match every word after `a` and in-between `!important!`.

So far i've got `(?<=!important!.*\ba\s)(\w+)`, which gives correct results but doesn't factor in the last part. I've tried a look-ahead but that didn't work. I'm pretty bad with regex so help is appreciated.

edit: i want to get `poor` and `sentence` as a result

Comment: Could you show how you tried the lookahead?

Comment: `(?<=!important!.*\ba\s)(\w+)(?=!important!)` which results in only giving back sentence

Comment: But isn't it the only word between `a` and `important`? Or is your actual aim to get `poor`, `example`, `of`, `a` and `sentence`?

Comment: i would like to get `poor` and `sentence` as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `poor` and `sentence`, you should add `.*` to the positive lookahead so that it will match as long as `!important!` is ahead (anywhere and not just immediately ahead):

```
(?<=!important!.*\ba\s)(\w+)(?=.*!important!)
```

Also, you can drop the capture group and then use `.Groups[0]` to get your match:

```
(?<=!important!.*\ba\s)\w+(?=.*!important!)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/lvwuMA)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, looks like you are using a variable length lookbehind assertion.
In general, I wouldn't use this. Remove it from the code if you need to.

```
 #  (?s)(?<=!important!(?:(?!\ba\s).)*\ba\s)((?:(?!!important!).)*)(?=!important!)

 (?s)                          # Dot all
 (?<=                          # Variable length look behind assertion (should not be used really)
      !important! 
      (?:
           (?! \b a \s )
           . 
      )*
      \b a \s 
 )

 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?! !important! )
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?= !important! )             # Look behind assertion (should not be used really)
```